# Error in fetching the image to the table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have successfully uploaded the image to the folder and stored the name of the image in the database now I'm trying to retrieve the uploaded image in my table, but I'm unable to retrieve that please can any one help me in this, it would be really helpful for me.

```
 ///my view page 
    <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <tr style="background:#CCC">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Update</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      $i=1;
      foreach($data as $row)
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->first_name."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->last_name."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->username."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->email."</td>";
      echo "<td>".<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$row->filename);?>" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">."</td>";
      echo "<td><a href='updatedata?id=".$row->ID."'>Update</a></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      $i++;
      }
       ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: whats the html output? whats the content of $data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already start `echo`, there's no need to `echo inside echo`:

```
echo '<td><img src="' . base_url('uploads/' . $row->filename) . '" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are a bit messed up and you have an echo inside an echo.

Replace this:

```
echo "<td>".<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$row->filename);?>" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='updatedata?id=".$row->ID."'>Update</a></td>";
```

With this:

```
echo '<td><img src="' . base_url('uploads/' . $row->filename) . '" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"></td>';
echo '<td><a href="updatedata?id=' . $row->ID . '">Update</a></td>';
```